# Javascript Checkboxes not getting checked after page reloaded

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have my HTML as:

===================================

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Red" onclick="changeURL('WineType', 'Red')"> Red (30499)
<input type="checkbox" id="White" onclick="changeURL('WineType', 'White')"> White (22840)
```

===================================

First I call changeURL()  and then isChecked() function.

But when both the functions gets executed, the check box is still unchecked.

===================================

```
function changeURL(fieldname, facetname) {
    var ref= window.location.href ;
    if(fieldname == "WineType") {
        var matchPrice = location.href.match(/&fq=%7B%21tag%3Ddt1%7DWineType%3A/);

        if(matchPrice == '&fq=%7B%21tag%3Ddt1%7DWineType%3A' )
        {
            var ndStart = ref.indexOf("WineType%3A%28");
            var ndEnd = ref.indexOf("%29",ndStart );        
            ref = ref.substring(0,ndStart+12) + ref.substring(ndStart+12, ndEnd) +" OR " +facetname + ref.substring(ndEnd);
        }
        else {
            ref = ref + "?&fq=%7B%21tag%3Ddt1%7DWineType%3A%28"+facetname+"%29";
        }
    }
    window.location.href = ref;
    isChecked(facetname);
};

function isChecked(element)
{
     var field = document.getElementById(element); 
     if (element) { 
          if (field.checked) { 
                document.getElementById(element).checked= false;
          } else { 
                document.getElementById(element).checked= true; 
          } 
     }   
};
```

Comment: use Firefox Firebug to debug please

Comment: (Not related to the answer) But why `if (field.checked == true)` required... why not `if (field.checked)` And see what you're doing. even if it is checked or unchecked you're making them check... Change your logic `if (field.checked == true) { 
                document.getElementById(element).checked= true;
          } else { 
                document.getElementById(element).checked= true; 
          }`

Comment: Hi,
I debugged the code using Firefox. 
The checkbox gets selected but when page refreshes it gets deselected

Comment: It's but obvious that on refreshing the check box will get deselected.. you can pass a querystring and then check the checkbox if you have so in the querystring. Ok. and try optimizing your code

Comment: @asifsid88; 
Yes, I understand the logic is wrong. However both IF and else results the code to select the check box. 
However The check box is yet not selected on page gets reloaded.

Comment: Where's the code that changes the checkboxes on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is tried here and is working for me as follows:
1) I sent the check-box status along with query string.
2) When page gets reloaded I extracts the check-box status from query string and then sets the status of check-box accordingly either **checked** or **unchecked**.

Answer (score 0):

make the use of localStorage and ensure that whenever checking/ unchecking is done you update your localStorage. With this whenever the page is loaded you first check your localStorage and if it is not empty then you mark checks on all the checkboxes using that. And if it is empty it means the page is loaded for the first time or no check was made.

The simplest way to implement localStorage: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)
This one is awesome: [Doc](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

P.S. Some people may have problem as I'm suggesting w3schools, but this is the simplest solution and implementation for localStorage for the person using it for the first time

Comment: Suggestion looks good to me, let me try that and will get back to you if it works as per my need.

Comment: @JayeshBhoyar All the best :)

Comment: This is not solving my Purpose.  :(